# sticky footer in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn

we already have [**stickyHeader**](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lists#sticky-headers) api available in jetpack compose. but how one can achieve something like **stickyFooter**?